# How to live stream audio on a mobile application and output to a external speaker in real time (C# .NET MAUI)

Tags: c#, .net, audio, stream, maui

I am tasked to create a mobile app funtionaluty where users can live stream voice to be outputted onto the external IP Speaker. (HIKVISION IP SPEAKER DS-PA0103-B). https://www.hikvision.com/uk/products/Accessories/CCTV-Accessories/ip-speaker/ds-pa0103-b/

For example, users can hold down the voice button and speak, and the IP speaker will output the audio in real-time. However I am unsure as to how to set this up and integrate my MAUI application to the speakers... Does anyone have any idea how to do so?

My current brief idea was to: utilise a audio plugin to record the audio and somehow send it to the Speaker in real time, however I have no idea as to how I can send the audio and connect it over to my speakers. Can someone please guide me on this? (please provide more specific steps) Thankyou.

Yet to try, since the product has yet been delivered however, I have no idea as of how to connect my speaker to my mobile application since there is no online resources on it :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

this is the isapi url you need to use, they are the same as Hikvision camera
#define HTTP_TWOWAY_AUDIO_OPEN_URL "/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/1/open" #define HTTP_TWOWAY_AUDIO_CLOSE_URL "/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/1/close" #define HTTP_GET_TWOWAY_AUDIO_URL "/ISAPI/System/TwoWayAudio/channels/1/audioData"

Comment: Hi, Paul Thank you for helping me out here but could you guide me on a few points?

1. The specific IP speaker's product description only says "one way audio" and I do not intend to connect the speaker to a HIKVISION camera. Does the HTTP_TWOWAY_AUDIO still works? Because I read through the ISAPI documentation and theres this "/ISAPI/System/Audio/AudioIn/channels/<ID>" therefore I am unsure of which API to use.

2. Could you guide me on what configurations do I have to make on the HIKVISION's web client in order to even use this API to send the audio stream to the speaker for output?